# Comparing big data sets

Tags: mysql, algorithm, nosql, mapreduce, diff

I'm looking for an effective way to compare 2 data sets that are too big to fit in memory(1M or more). I have them both in MySQL as tables. I'm trying to find difference between server and client and find what to update, create and delete on client. I can sort data before or keep them sorted.

```
input:
server = [
  {:id => 7, :rev => 1, :uuid => 111},
  {:id => 8, :rev => 3, :uuid => 222},
  {:id => 9, :rev => 1, :uuid => 333},
  ]

client = [
  {:id => 8, :rev => 2, :uuid => 222},
  {:id => 9, :rev => 1, :uuid => 333},
  {:id => 6, :rev => 1, :uuid => 444},
  ]

expected output:
create: [{:id => 7, :rev => 1, :uuid => 111}]
update: [{:id => 8, :rev => 3, :uuid => 222}]
delete: [{:id => 6, :rev => 1, :uuid => 444}]
```

I'm looking for a way to divide this diff problem and distribute it over several workers/nodes. I can use different datastore and it would be great if it can be done on datastore and not in ruby or c. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash of key of your data and distribute work accordingly. Ex. Assume a simple hash function that is "id mod 2". So all the even ids are handled by one machine and all the odd ids are handled by the second machine.

On each individual machine, the data needs to be in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use programming languages o ther than the SQL, look at the following MySQL features:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to distribute the work, you should use a MapReduce framework such as Hadoop.

The idea is that you `map` over both client and server, sending every record to a key which is its `id`, and a value that indicates which it came from, and the values that it has.

The `reduce` will then only have to deal with the records for a single `id`, and it has straightforward logic.

The framework takes care of distributing the work, how to handle machine failures, etc.

That said, if you only have 1 million records each, just put it in order locally, suck down the entire remote set in order, and walk them in parallel.  It will likely execute quickly enough, and you'll save yourself a lot of headaches in setting up/using the remote framework.